# A question in proof of a theorem in Chapter - The quadratic reciprocity Law of David Burton

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am self studying  number theory from David M Burton and I have a question in theorem on page 182 of 7 th edition whose image I am adding below. 
[image]

I am unable to understand why there must exist an odd prime which divides N. N is is even. So, how the author deducted this!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$N\equiv2\pmod 4$. But $N>2$ and so $N$ cannot be a power of $2$. Therefore $N$ must have an odd prime factor.

Comment: unfortunately I have another question in same proof. Can you please explain. If all odd prime divisors are of form 8a+1 then why must N be of form 8a+1 . I am not able to deduce it. Please help!!

Comment: can you please help me with this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621731/a-question-regarding-change-of-index-of-summation-in-analytic-number-theory

Comment: please see edit of this question.i just want to know what mistake I am making. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621731/a-question-regarding-change-of-index-of-summation-in-analytic-number-theory