# A question regarding change of index of summation in analytic number theory

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-convolution

I am trying exercises of Apostol's Dirichlet Series and Modular Functions in Number Theory and I am unable to get past an argument in this question.

[!Original Question statement of book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovXLt.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovXLt.jpg)

->[!Defination of $G_2(\tau)$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCmtK.jpg) ][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CCmtK.jpg)

[!Equation (12)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNqkH.jpg)][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNqkH.jpg)

[!What I tried in the question/My attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvGrl.jpg)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvGrl.jpg)

Can someone please help how to complete it!!

Comment: What do you mean? Here $n$ is a dummy variable, introduced by the sum. The only true "variable" there is $\tau$.

Comment: @LukeCollins i am asking how to remove r from summation so that only n remains

Comment: @Luke Collins see image 2 !!

Comment: Do you know the definition of $\sigma$?

Comment: @Cameron Williams yes

Comment: @CameronWilliams I am confused how to use it here. I know it will be used but I am unable to use. Please help!!

Comment: @Cameron Williams can you please help!!

Comment: Assuming $\sigma(n)$ is the sum of divisors function, it follows that $\sigma(n) = \sum_{d|n} d$.

Comment: @Enver I have already written it. Kindly see question's last paragraph!!

Comment: @Enver it seems I am making some stupid mistake. I have also posted answer image. Can you please tell where I am making mistake!!

Comment: can u rewrite your question. it's all over the place

Comment: @mathworker21 see it now!!

Comment: @TimGreen no. you ask a question near the start and then a question at the end. ask one question and make it clear exactly what you are asking

Comment: @mathworker21 is it fine now?

Comment: @mathworker  can you please help. It's a small problem but still bothering me!!

Comment: @TimGreen it's not fine now. there's a link, then a picture, then a question statement at the end. look at how other people ask their questions

Comment: @mathworker21 kindly check it again!!

Comment: @TimGreen this is very simple: look at how other people ask their questions

Comment: @mathworker21 I hope its in best way communicicated now. Thanks for your patience and advice!!

Comment: @TimGreen Is your question just: prove that $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} r e^{2πirn\tau} = \sum_{q|n} qe^{2πin\tau}$ for any positive integer $n$ and real number $\tau$?

Comment: @mathworker21 yes!!

Comment: @marhworker21 I am struck on this, In general Question is what is mentioned in 1 st image ie Question 3.1 of Apostol. But I am struck on this part mentioned in your comment. For more information see 4 th image ( My attempt) .

Comment: @TimGreen It's false for $\tau = 0$. There's no way it's true.

Comment: @mathworker21 if you read the question ( Link 1) then you will come to know what I mean and what I want to ask  .

Comment: @TimGreen I just asked if that's what you wanted to ask and you said "yes". I am done with this. goodbye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the notes and you have a double sum in two variables $n,r$ in the next to last line as you sum on $n$ in a sum on $r$, so the sum is:
$S=\sum_{n \ge 1}\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} r e^{2πirn\tau} $

Note that in the original sum with $\frac{1}{(n\tau+m)^2}$ terms you can extend the sum to all nonzero integers in $n$ using the trick that $\frac{1}{(n\tau+m)^2}=\frac{1}{(-n\tau-m)^2}$ and the sum in $m$ is on full integers, so you get double and take care of the coefficient $2$ in equation $(49)$ but in the sum $S$ above $n$ must be positive for convergence - so this may be a source of confusion here, as $n$ is just a summation variable in both with similar but not quite identical meanings)

But now you switch variables to $q=nr$ (allowable by compact absolute convergence when $\Im \tau >0$) remembering that in $S$ above you can have only $n \ge 1$ as the $n$ negative appears only in the original sum you start with where the terms are $\frac{1}{(n\tau+m)^2}$), it is clear that $\sum_{r|q} re^{2πiq\tau}=\sigma(q)e^{2πiq\tau}$ so you get that $S=\sum_{q \ge 1}(\sum_{(r,n), rn=q}r e^{2πiq\tau})=\sum_{q \ge 1}\sigma(q)e^{2πiq\tau}$ and then changing variables back to $q=n$ you are done!

Note that the $n$ in the end (in the terms $\sigma(n)e^{2πin\tau}$) and the $n$ in the beginning (in the terms $\frac{1}{(n\tau+m)^2}$) have completely different meanings as they are just summation variables so that may be another source of confusion

Summarizing - the computations are straightforward per the hint and compact absolute convergence for $\Im \tau >0$ allows switching double sums and changing variables in them almost at will, but the usage of the summing variable $n$ in several different contexts with different meanings may lead to confusion

Comment: why sum upon n must be +ve for convergence? Can you please tell which results are you using?

Comment: $|e^{2πirn\tau}|=e^{-2πrn\Im \tau}$ so we need $rn >0$ (hence $n>0$) for convergence since $\Im \tau >0$

Comment: Thanks a lot!! It was very kind of you to help. A lot of people ignored it.

Comment: happy to be of help - from my experience a lot of confusion comes from naming dummy summation variables same in very different contexts and it takes practice to get it at a glance as your notes were almost complete

Comment: can you please help me with this question. If you have some time to spare and knowledge about sieve theory. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3633775/about-the-research-papers-which-led-to-beginning-of-sieve-theory?noredirect=1#comment7468859_3633775