# Implication of Prime Number Theorem to prove a result related to $d_n =\operatorname{lcm}\left\{ 1 ,2,\ldots,n \right\}$

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory

It is known that prime number theorem implies $\lim _{n \to  + \infty }\frac {\log(d_n)}{n} =1$.

> I am given an exercise on proving $\lim _{n \to  + \infty } \frac{\log D_{2n}^{ a+b-1}} {n} = 2(a+b-1)$ assuming prime number theorem but I have no idea how to do it. ($a$, $b$ belongs to integers) .
>
> Can someone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean the limit

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\log d_{2n}^{a+b-1}}{n}.$$

Now, notice that

$$\frac{\log d_{2n}^{a+b-1}}{n} = 2(a+b-1) \frac{\log d_{2n}}{2n}.$$

Taking $n \to \infty$ yields

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} 2(a+b-1) \frac{\log d_{2n}}{2n} = 2(a+b-1).$$

Comment: how did you deduced the mathematical equaltion after the line ->" Now notice that "?

Comment: For any real $n,x>0$, $\log x^n = n\log x$ and $1/x = 2/(2x)$. Combine these two to obtain $$\frac{\log d_{2n}^{a+b-1}}{n} = \frac{(a+b-1)\log d_{2n}}{2 \cdot (1/2)n} = 2(a+b-1) \frac{\log d_{2n}}{2n}.$$

Comment: thanks that was stupid to ask!!

Comment: can you please look at this question asked by me if you have some time to spare!! I t has a bounty of 50 on it!! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3621731/a-question-regarding-change-of-index-of-summation-in-analytic-number-theory